# Parent to another Custom Post Type - Template files not being recognized

Tags: custom-post-types, templates

I have two custom post types - `'gaming-consoles'` and `'xbox-games'`.

I also have two custom templates for these post types: `single-gaming-consoles.php` and `single-xbox-games.php` - which worked great.

I ran into a problem due I wanted the following URL-stucture on my website:

```
website.com/gaming-consoles/xbox/             <--- Custom Post Type 'gaming-consoles' 
website.com/gaming-consoles/xbox/xbox-games/  <--- Custom Post Type 'xbox-games'
```

Custom post types **can't** have other types of custom post types as a parent.

So I used the [following solution made by Janina](http://janina.tumblr.com/post/3588081423/post-parent-different-type) to make it work, and solved it.

```
add_action('admin_menu', function() { remove_meta_box('pageparentdiv', 'xbox-games', 'normal');});
add_action('add_meta_boxes', function() { add_meta_box('chapter-parent', 'gaming-consoles', 'chapter_attributes_meta_box', 'xbox-games', 'side', 'high');});
function chapter_attributes_meta_box($post) {
    $post_type_object = get_post_type_object($post->post_type);
        if ( $post_type_object->hierarchical ) {
            $pages = wp_dropdown_pages(array('post_type' => 'gaming-consoles', 'selected' => $post->post_parent, 'name' => 'parent_id', 'show_option_none' => __('(no parent)'), 'sort_column'=> 'menu_order, post_title', 'echo' => 0));
        if ( ! empty($pages) ) {
        echo $pages;
        } // end empty pages check
    } // end hierarchical check.
}
```

I also used [this solution by Pablo Vallejo](http://pablovallejo.me/removing-custom-post-type-url/) to remove the Slug `/gaming-consoles/` - so the URLs becomes just the following:

```
website.com/xbox/                            <--- Custom Post Type 'gaming-consoles' 
website.com/xbox/xbox-games/                 <--- Custom Post Type 'xbox-games'
```

Now, the custom page of `website.com/xbox/` is *working* but `website.com/xbox/xbox-games/` *is not*. I am getting the index.php instead of the page content.

The `single-xbox-games.php` starts with:

```
<?php
    /*
     Template Name: Xbox-games Template
    */
?>
```

As I said, it worked before I added the parent functionality.

According to the [Template Hierarchy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Single_Post_display) it seems that Wordpress is looking for another name than `single-xbox-games.php`.

Anyone got an idea how to display the template for `'xbox-games'`?

Comment: You have https://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-to-posts/ to relate cpt to cpt

Comment: This is solved, my problem is that Wordpress is not finding the template for the custom post type `'xbox-games'`

Comment: My guess is that is rewrite rules problem and not a template name issue. Use a tool like https://wordpress.org/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/ to check what it's trying to load.

Comment: Not sure how to use this tool. What URL's should I try with?